# How to get a text between two (same) separators?

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

I know how to get a text between two DIFFERENT separators, However, I don't know between two of the same.

example:

```
"12345@@WantedText@@somethingHere"
```

All I need is to extract the number `12345` and what is between `@@` and `@@`
so the final result is:  `12345(WantedText)`

NOTE: this is in C# WinForms

Comment: Is the separator ALWAYS going to be `@@`, both starting and ending?

Comment: `var parts = input.Split(new[] {"@@"}, StringSplitOptions.None); var result = $"{parts[0]}({parts[1]});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.Split` to split the string into parts delimited by your `"@@"` token.  Then recompose the bits back into your desired result:

```
     var text = "12345@@WantedText@@somethingHere";
     var parts = text.Split(new []{"@@"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     var result = $"{parts[0]}({parts[1]})";
```

The result is:

```
    12345(WantedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.Split() for that. It is not the most performant method, but it does its job.

`"12345@@MWantedText@@somethingHere".Split(new string[] { "@@" }, StringSplitOptions.None);` will return an `string[]` with three entries:

1. 12345
2. MWantedText
3. somethingHere

Then you can use this information however you want.

This is just an example, of course you would have to use a real string and the thing you want to split by. You can also provide multiple splits. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)